# What is the correct way to retrieve fundraising data from messari.io - using Selenium or an API?

Tags: python-3.x, api, selenium-webdriver, cryptography, selenium-chromedriver

I have a paid account on Messari.io website and I want to scrape its fundraising data table from the page https://messari.io/fundraising-data.

First, I logged in to the site and navigated to the fundraising data table. Since it is within an iframe, I switched to the iframe view and correctly identified the table path. However, I am only able to scrape the data that is currently visible, which includes only three columns at a time until I scroll to the left to load more columns. This is quite frustrating, and the same issue applies to scrolling through the rows.

I tried to collapse the columns using ActionChains, but without success - it actually made the issue worse.

Here is the code I tried:

**Login and getting iframe table (working fine)**

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from selenium.common.exceptions import (TimeoutException,
                                        NoSuchElementException,
                                        StaleElementReferenceException,
                                        NoSuchWindowException,
                                        MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException)
from selenium_stealth import stealth

driver = Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = 200
driver.get("https://messari.io/login")
driver.implicitly_wait(wait)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").send_keys("mail")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys("pass")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > div > main > section > div > div > div > form > div.c1b766a1c > '
                                      'button').click()

funding_site = "https://messari.io/fundraising-data"
driver.get(funding_site)
driver.implicitly_wait(wait)

wwait =  WebDriverWait(driver, 200, ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,
                                                                                StaleElementReferenceException))
wwait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, "airtable-embed")))

table = wwait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#view > div > div.paneContainer > div.headerAndDataRowContainer "
                              "> div.rightPaneWrapper > "
                              "div.dataRightPane.pane.no-events-when-cell-selection-disabled > "
                              "div.dataRightPaneInnerContent.paneInnerContent")))
```

**Tied to get data of table (gives few columns and rows)**

```
rows = table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-rowid]")
columns_data = {"project_name": [], "date": [], "stage": [], "investor": [], "category": [], "source": [],
                "website": []}
for row in rows:
    separated_boxs = row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div")
    if "unknown" in separated_boxs[9].text.lower().strip() or \
            "series" in separated_boxs[9].text.lower().strip():
        continue

    columns_data["project_name"].append(separated_boxs[0].text.split("-")[0].strip())
    columns_data["date"].append(separated_boxs[1].text)
    columns_data["investor"].append(separated_boxs[3].text)
    columns_data["website"].append(separated_boxs[4].text)
    columns_data["category"].append(separated_boxs[6].text)
    columns_data["stage"].append(separated_boxs[9].text)

    columns_data["source"].append(funding_site)
    print(columns_data)
```

**Tried to resize table to get all the columns in one view (not working)**

```
drag_lines = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "resizeHandle")
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
for drag_line in range(len(drag_lines)):
    try:
        current_size = drag_lines[drag_line].size["width"]
        action_chains.click_and_hold(drag_lines[drag_line]).move_by_offset(-current_size, 0).release().perform()
    except MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:
        ...
```

**If you know how can I get data let me know please**

***If you're wondering why I'm not using an API here, the answer is simple: I have an API key, but I haven't been able to find a way to access fundraising data with it. If you know how to retrieve fundraising data using the API, please let me know. I've tried to read the documentation, but I've only found information on the assets, markets, news, and timeseries endpoints. Here's the documentation site: https://messari.io/api/docs.***

**Dynamically loading Table Image**
[image: table_image]

**The ideal resized columns I wanted (the size dynamically changes)**
[image: resized_image]